# Why does this SQL query for getting DotNetNuke roles return incorrect values?

Tags: sql, dotnetnuke

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 1 AS 'CurrentUserID',
    UserPortals.UserPortalId AS PassedUserId,
    UserPortals.PortalId,
    Roles.RoleID,
    Roles.RoleName,
    UserRoles.ExpiryDate,
    UserRoles.LastModifiedOnDate
FROM UserRoles
INNER JOIN Roles
ON Roles.RoleID = UserRoles.RoleID
INNER JOIN UserPortals
ON UserRoles.UserID = UserPortals.UserPortalId
WHERE userportals.UserPortalId = 1 AND Roles.RoleID IN
(SELECT RoleID FROM UserRoles WHERE UserID = 1)
```

Here is the data it returns:

```
CurrentUserID | PassedUserId | PortalId | RoleID |     RoleName       | ExpiryDate              | LastModifiedOnDate
      1       |       1      |    0     |   0    | Administrators     | 2019-04-19 00:00:00.000 | 2018-04-19 16:37:17.313
      1       |       1      |    0     |   1    | Registered Users   | 2018-04-20 00:00:00.000 | 2018-04-19 14:02:35.197
      1       |       1      |    0     |   2    | Subscribers        | 2018-04-20 00:00:00.000 | 2018-04-19 11:25:21.913
      1       |       1      |    0     |   3    | Translator (en-US) | 2018-04-20 00:00:00.000 | 2018-04-19 12:42:12.760
      1       |       1      |    0     |   4    | Unverified Users   | 2018-04-20 00:00:00.000 | 2018-04-19 12:43:40.883
      1       |       1      |    0     |   5    | Administrators     | NULL                    | 2018-04-19 13:24:04.347
      1       |       1      |    0     |   6    | Registered Users   | NULL                    | 2018-04-19 13:24:04.580
      1       |       1      |    0     |   7    | Subscribers        | NULL                    | 2018-04-19 13:24:04.813
      1       |       1      |    0     |   8    | Translator (en-US) | 2018-04-20 00:00:00.000 | 2018-04-19 13:33:54.530
      1       |       1      |    0     |   9    | Unverified Users   | 2018-04-20 00:00:00.000 | 2018-04-19 13:36:12.537
```

The problem is that PortalId (the third column) contains all zeros, when the second half of it is supposed to be all ones. It should look like this:

```
CurrentUserID | PassedUserId | PortalId | RoleID |     RoleName       | ExpiryDate              | LastModifiedOnDate
    1         |     1        |    0     |   0    | Administrators     | 2019-04-19 00:00:00.000 | 2018-04-19 16:37:17.313
    1         |     1        |    0     |   1    | Registered Users   | 2018-04-20 00:00:00.000 | 2018-04-19 14:02:35.197
    1         |     1        |    0     |   2    | Subscribers        | 2018-04-20 00:00:00.000 | 2018-04-19 11:25:21.913
    1         |     1        |    0     |   3    | Translator (en-US) | 2018-04-20 00:00:00.000 | 2018-04-19 12:42:12.760
    1         |     1        |    0     |   4    | Unverified Users   | 2018-04-20 00:00:00.000 | 2018-04-19 12:43:40.883
    1         |     1        |    **1** |   5    | Administrators     | NULL                    | 2018-04-19 13:24:04.347
    1         |     1        |    **1** |   6    | Registered Users   | NULL                    | 2018-04-19 13:24:04.580
    1         |     1        |    **1** |   7    | Subscribers        | NULL                    | 2018-04-19 13:24:04.813
    1         |     1        |    **1** |   8    | Translator (en-US) | 2018-04-20 00:00:00.000 | 2018-04-19 13:33:54.530
    1         |     1        |    **1** |   9    | Unverified Users   | 2018-04-20 00:00:00.000 | 2018-04-19 13:36:12.537
```

Comment: I think you want to join on `UserPortals.UserId` instead of `ON UserRoles.UserID = UserPortals.UserPortalId`

Comment: @SirajK turn that into an answer! That appears to be correct

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to join on `UserPortals.UserId` instead of `ON UserRoles.UserID = UserPortals.UserPortalId`

And this should be `UserPortals.UserId` in `UserPortals.UserPortalId AS PassedUserId`

Comment: I think another thing it would have to have is "WHERE userportals.UserId" instead of "WHERE userportals.UserPortalId". Is this correct?